# AlpacaJS Tables - Pushing data and adding placeholders

Tags: json, datatables, alpacajs

Posted this on Alapaca's Stack Overflow but I know they are busy / don't respond very promptly so hopefully someone else can assist with this question.

I've got a table. The number of rows is set by another element using a postRender script. But, I can't get any values set in the elements when I push. Here's the code:

Schema

```
"required": false,
"properties": {
  "study_group_radio": {
    "enum": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  },
  "study_group_table": {
    "type": "array",
    "required": false,
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "study_group": {
          "title": "Study Groups",
          "type": "number",
          "readonly": true
        },
        "dose": {
          "title": "Dose",
          "type": "string"
         },
        "route": {
          "title": "Route",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "doses": {
          "title": "# Doses",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "animals_main": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Animals Main"
        },
        "animals_recovery": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Animals Recovery"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Options

```
{
"type": "object",
"fields": {
  "study_group_radio": {
    "type": "radio",
    "helper": "the number of selected will generate a table"
  },
  "study_group_table": {
    "type": "table",
    "id": "study_group_table",
    "label": "New table",
    "animate": true,
    "hideNone": true,
    "toolbarStyle": "button",
    "actionbarStyle": "right",
    "items": {
      "type": "tablerow"
    },
    "hideToolbarWithChildren": true,
    "datatables": {
      "paging": false,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "info": false,
      "searching": false,
      "ordering": true,
      "columns": [
        {
          "orderable": false,
          "name": "actions",
          "bSortable": false,
          "sName": "actions"
        }
      ],
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "aoColumns": [
        {
          "orderable": false,
          "name": "actions",
          "bSortable": false,
          "sName": "actions"
        }
      ],
      "bSort": true,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "bFilter": false
    },
    "dragRows": false,
    "showActionsColumn": false,
    "fields": {
      "dose": {
        "placeholder": "e.g. 1 mg/kg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Postrender

```
control.childrenByPropertyId["study_group_radio"].on("change", function() {
  var times = this.getValue();
  var value = 
  control.childrenByPropertyId["study_group_table"].getValue(value);

  if (value.length < times) {
      for (var i = value.length; i < times; i++) {
          console.log(i+1);
          value.push({
              "study_group": (i+1),
              "dose": "",
              "route": "",
              "doses": "",
              "animals_main": "",
              "animals_recovery": ""
          });
      }
  } else {
      while (value.length > times) {
          value.pop();
      }
  }
  console.log(value.study_group);
  control.childrenByPropertyId["study_group_table"].setValue(value);
});
```

The table Options were pre-populated by using the sample form builder. Unfortunately, I can't get the table to work right when I'm manually entering the code. I have religiously studied the 10 examples in AlpacaJS's table documentation but what worked for them doesn't seem to be working for me!

Issues:

I'm trying to number the "study_group" column automatically. The postRender code creates the correct number of rows but they are always blank, despite adding a value (i+1).

I can't figure out how to add placeholders using Alpaca. I can do it by manually manipulating the html after rendering. You can see I tried it on "dose" in Options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you need to add a data object for the table and set it to empty to solve the empty rows issue.

```
"data": {
  "study_group_table": []
}
```

For the placeholder issue you you must wrap `"fields"` into `"items"` property.

```
"items": {
  "fields": {
    "dose": {
      "placeholder": "e.g. 1 mg/kg"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/o2hr6wc7/) for this.
Tell me if you need something else, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks! I actually did figure out the placeholder issue, sorry for not updating this... 

Unfortunately, the way we use Alpaca does not allow me to set anything in the data object so I'm banging my head against postRender. Was finally able to get numbering to work, now working on setting the cells to readonly _after_ adding the numbering (setting readonly = true in schema stops me from being able to add numbering).

Comment: Okay so I re-added the Data object... And figured out that setting `readonly` works if it's set through Options... wouldn't work properly when set through Schema. Thanks again for the response!

Now I'm working on making the table rows re-size based on content...